# producing all anagrams in a string c++

Tags: c++, c

I saw this problem online, and I was trying to solve it in `C++`. I have the following algorithm:

```
char permutations( const char* word ){

  int size = strlen( word );
  if( size <= 1 ){
      return word;
  }
  else{
    string output = word[ 0 ];
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
        output += permutations( word );
        cout << output << endl;
        output = word[ i ];
     }
  }
  return "";
}
```

For example, if I have `abc` as my input, I want to display `abc`, `acb`, `bac`, `bca`, `cab`, `cba`.
So, what I'm trying to do is

```
'abc' => 'a' + 'bc' => 'a' + 'b' + 'c'
                    => 'a' + 'c' + 'b'
```

so I need o pass a `word` less char every function call.
Could someone please help how to do it?

Comment: Why return `""` from a function returning `char`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Nothing to return at all? I just want to print the anagrams.

Comment: `""` is of type `const char[]`, and **not** `char`. This *will* break your code.

Comment: Why this question has received negative votes I do not understand. Is it the reason that it's more suited for programmers.SX?

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm open to any suggestions you may have ... I could do it void, but I want to return a `char` every time.

Comment: @philippe There is already [std::next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) available in the algorithm header. Can't you use it ?

Comment: @ShashankSawant I agree with you, please here in SO is losing their sense. I would like those whom is voting negative to show up their opinion before doing so.

Comment: @Mahesh This was an Amazon interview, so I can't use built-in libraries.

Comment: There are many algorithms to do this, the more efficient of them accounting for letter duplication and avoiding repetitions, which honestly is the reason this is on your interview in the first place. Strings like ABBA, though four letters long, have fewer than maximum permutations based solely on numbers of letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest doing it using the `algorithm` header library in C++, much easier; and as a function can be written like this:

```
void anagram(string input){
    sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    do
        cout << input << endl;
    while(next_permutation(input.begin(), input.end()));
}
```

However since you want it without the STL, you can do it like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char ch = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = ch;
};

void permutate_(char* str, size_t index )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t slen = strlen(str);
    char lastChar = 0;

    if (index == slen )
    {
        puts(str);
        return;
    }

    for (i = index; i < slen; i++ )
    {
        if (lastChar == str[i])
            continue;
        else
            lastChar = str[i];

        swap(str+index, str+i);
        permutate_(str, index + 1);
        swap(str+index, str+i);
    }
}

// pretty lame, but effective, comparitor for determining winner
static int cmpch(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(char*)a - *(char*)b );
}

// loader for real permutor
void permutate(char* str)
{
    qsort(str, strlen(str), sizeof(str[0]), cmpch);
    permutate_(str, 0);
}
```

Which you can call by sending it a sorted array of characters,

```
permutate("Hello World");
```

The non-STL approach was gotten [from here.](http://www.mytechinterviews.com/permutations-of-a-string)

Comment: I knew about this library brother, but this was an Amazon interview, and I was asked to implement that procedure without using STL.

Comment: @philippe, okay, give me a minute.

Comment: @Link This needs to be fixed. Apart from the compilation errors, which are numerous, the static lastChar is NOT supposed to be static. I hope philippe figured that out too.

Answer (score 0):

The STL is wonderful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void permutations(const char *word) {
    string s = word;
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    cout << s << endl;
    while(next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()))
        cout << s << endl;
}

int main() {
    permutations("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, `next_permutation` can be implemented quite simply. From the end of the string, iterate backwards until you find an element `x` which is less than the next element. Swap `x` with the next value larger than `x` in the remainder of the string, and reverse the elements coming afterwards. So, `abcd` becomes `abdc` since `c < d`; `cdba` becomes `dabc` since `c < d` and we flip the last three letters of `dcba`; `bdca` becomes `cabd` because `b < d` and we swap `b` for `c`.

Comment: Is there any reason to sort the string ?

Comment: I knew about this library brother, but this was an Amazon interview, and I was asked to implement that procedure without using STL.

Comment: @Mahesh: `next_permutation` produces permutations in lexicographically increasing order, so you have to start with the minimum string (which is the string in sorted order).

Comment: @philippe: so, you didn't see the problem online then; it was an interview question?

Comment: I saw it in CareerCup for an Amazon interview, which I was practicing for.